# Unable to connect to node database in Corda Nodes

Tags: database, corda

[Image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi73H.png)

Following is jdbc url of node one, PartyA:

```
Database connection url is              : jdbc:h2:tcp://172.16.55.151:55221/node
```

Unable to connect to jdbc url through H2 DataBase engine.

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://172.16.55.151:55221/

```
Connection to 172.16.55.151 failed.
The system returned: (110) Connection timed out
```

[Image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ewQS.png)

Comment: That's an address in a local IP range, so it's likely a connectivity or service problem inside your network. Collect as much diagnostic information as you can e.g. can you connect to that address from a browser, or ping them machine, then you'll have to talk to someone in your organisation to get this resolved.

Comment: Check the logs in the path shown on line : "Logs can be found in :".

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it's pretty hard to know what's going on here.

Just make sure to use the correct IP address, make sure you've got the right credentials. You should verify this by making sure you can access the node over ssh.

It's worth mentioning that it's easier now to connect using H2 in newer releases of Corda.

You can find that information in the docs here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-database-access-h2.html